# After Security Update 2019-003, OpenLDAP is corrupted. How can I recover?

Tags: time-machine, high-sierra, restore, server.app, open-directory

I installed the Security Update 2019-003 this morning. The update went awry, and produced on (postgres) induced panic on the host, a second attempt succeeded. After the update, slapd will not launch anymore.

I've tried restoring /private/var/db/{krb5kdc,openldap,auth} from a Time Machine backup (through Cmd-R reboot, including temporarily turning SIP off) but whatever I do, I can't get it running again. db_recover won't help either. slapd testing produces:

```
bash-3.2# /usr/libexec/slapd -T test
5cdfeed8 bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
5cdfeed8 bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
5cdfeed8 bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
config file testing succeeded
bash-3.2# slaptest -v
5cdfef28 bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
5cdfef28 bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
5cdfef28 bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
config file testing succeeded
```

How can I recover this from my Time Machine backup without completely restoring the server and overwriting everything else?

Apparently the restore I tried (copy openldap over from a Time Machine backup) did not work as Postgres DB-recovery balks at what is in authdata:

```
bash-3.2# db_recover -cv -h authdata/
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 31 offset 174121
Recovery starting from [30][28]
db_recover: Log sequence error: page LSN 23 1709981; previous LSN 30 28
db_recover: Recovery function for LSN 30 8130 failed on forward pass
db_recover: PANIC: Invalid argument
db_recover: process-private: unable to find environment
db_recover: DB_ENV->open: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
bash-3.2# db_recover -cv -h openldap-data/
Finding last valid log LSN: file: 1 offset 1754044
Recovery starting from [1][28]
Recovery complete at Sat May 18 13:45:46 2019
Maximum transaction ID 80000cad Recovery checkpoint [1][1754044]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to repair this. It may have been luck. What I did:

1. Copy all private/var/db/openldap/authdata from all Time Machine
   backups to a working directory (`for i in 2019*; do ditto $i/DumbledoreRoot/private/var/db/openldap/authdata/ /tmp/$i/authdata; done`). My boot volume is called `DumbledoreRoot`.
2. Run crash recovery on all the authdata copies, to see which one are
   recoverable (`for i in 2019-0*; do echo $i; db_recover -cv -h $i/authdata/; done`)
3. Most would report an error. This is not strange, Time Machine cannot
   really backup this data as backing up a live database mostly gets
   incorrect results in the backup. I do wonder how restore from a Time
   Machine does this, though. There must be a better way.
4. Replace `/private/var/db/authdata` with what is in that backup. I
   probably should have copied `openldap-data` as well, given what
   happened next
5. Ran `slapd -T test` and noticed there still was some corruption (though different):

Output:

```
bash-3.2# /usr/libexec/slapd -T test
5cdff90d bdb_db_open: database "dc=Dumbledore,dc=local": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
5cdff90d bdb_db_open: database "dc=Dumbledore,dc=local": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
5cdff90d bdb_monitor_db_open: monitoring disabled; configure monitor database to enable
5cdff90d bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": unclean shutdown detected; attempting recovery.
5cdff90d bdb_db_open: database "cn=authdata": recovery skipped in read-only mode. Run manual recovery if errors are encountered.
config file testing succeeded
```

Despaired. Then on a whim, started Open Directory from Server.app and to my surprise, it started and my network user accounts were back.

So, I'm probably just lucky and better answers may help future problems.

Comment: This answer helped me when db_recover failed to repair authdata. It seems the file can be broken in a way that it cannot be repaired any more. Then there's no alternative to going back in time in your Time Machine backups. :-(